# Why does Quarkus complain about my (unused) @ApplicationScoped data class with a @ConfigProperty property?

Tags: kotlin, cdi, quarkus

This kotlin data class is part of an internal library used in some Quarkus microservices (Quarkus 2.0.0.Final):

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
data class FooConfiguration(
  @ConfigProperty(name = "foo.bar")
  val fooBar: String
)
```

The library is used in a few microservices, and most of them do use that configuration. But some are not. For those, the `foo.bar` property is not defined in the `application.properties`. I would expect this to not matter at all, as those services are never injecting a `FooConfiguration`, so I'd expect that to never be constructed.

However, the application refuses startup with this error message:

```
SRCFG00014: The config property foo.bar is required but it could not be found in any config source
```

I know how to workaround this issue (simply supplying a nonsense value), but I currently wonder why this is an issue in the first place. The configuration bean should never get constructed. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a MicroProfile Config-related issue.

Your `foo.bar` property [is *optional*, not required, in the parlance of the MicroProfile Config specification](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.microprofile.config/microprofile-config-api/2.0/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/inject/ConfigProperty.html), because a value for it is not present in any configuration source, as you have indicated.  To inject a value for an optional MicroProfile Config configuration property, you need to use `java.util.Optional`.  I don't know Kotlin, so here is what it would look like in Java:

```java
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "foo.bar")
private Optional<String> fooBar;
```

Comment: Thanks! I could use `Optional` (kotlin normally uses nullable types, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types), but that models a slightly different use-case. The value itself is not optional for cases where the configuration bean is injected. Is there any easy way to model that?

I'm totally fine with it breaking on startup when the value is missing for cases where I need it. I actually want it that way. Just not when not using the bean itself that contains it.

Comment: MicroProfile Config (and CDI overall to a certain extent) requires that all injection points be validated, for better and for worse, so you'll either need to treat this property as optional (if indeed there are cases where a value is not present in a configuration source) or as required (in which case you need a default/fallback value to be present).